# What causes "undefined function" date_diff?

Tags: php, date

i have this script which i'm using in my php to convert a users date of birth to their age.
It works fine on my local host but when i upload it to the server the page comes up with this error:

> Fatal error: **Call to undefined function date_diff()** in /home/content/31/9118831/html/projects/mark.ptb/PTB1/includes/mod_home/mod_platinum.php on line 19

Here's my code, i'm guessing i've not defined the function although i can't understand why it would work fine on my localhost therefore?

```
<?php
 $dob = $platinum['dob'];

function age_from_dob($dob) {


       $age = date_diff(date_create($dob), date_create('now'))->y;  
       return $age;
}

?>

<?

        $platinum_set = get_platinum_users();
        while ($platinum = mysql_fetch_array($platinum_set)) {
        $age = age_from_dob($platinum['dob']);
             echo "
            <div class=\"platinumcase\">
            <a href=\"profile.php?id={$platinum['id']}\"><img width=80px height= 80px src=\"data/photos/{$platinum['id']}/_default.jpg\" class=\"boxgrid\"/></a><h58> {$platinum['first_name']} {$platinum['last_name']}</h58><br/><br/><h52> ".$age." Years Old<br/><br/>From {$platinum['location']}</h52>

            </div>";
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: (Pay attention to error messages - they are *usually* helpful and relatively direct. Use these as the starting point for inquiries about "what is wrong". Once that is understood, fixing it is much simpler. I removed the tags that aren't related and surfaced "the real problem"; once again, focus on the error(s) first.)

Answer (score 1):

The [`date_diff()`](http://php.net/date_diff) function is part of PHP >= 5.3. If it doesn't exist on the server but it does on your local machine, then the server is using an older version of PHP while you're using PHP >= 5.3.

It's a good idea to always develop using the same version of PHP as the deployment environment. To find out what PHP version you're using, you can `echo` the `PHP_VERSION` constant.

Comment: so does that mean my server who i host with doesn't support php 5.3?

Comment: @AdamWalker, if it does, then it's not the one you're using. You should contact support and ask.

Answer (score 1):

According to the php [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php), date_diff is only available in PHP 5.3+

Is the version of PHP on the server sufficient? You can use `phpinfo()` command to determine what version of PHP is being used on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it just a bit wrong :)

```
$date = new DateTime($dob);
$diff = $date->diff('now')->y;
```

Make sure to catch errors as the user-specified `$dob` string may not always result in a valid date.

Comment: @rid, that's not true. `date_diff()` was introduced in PHP 5.3. [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) was introduced in PHP 5.2.

Comment: You're right. What I should have said explicitly is that the [`DateTime::diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method that you're using in your example won't be available. It was introduced at the exact same time as `date_diff()`.

Answer (score 0):

Please use date object instead of date_diff() function. you can use $date->diff() function to calculate date difference
For example:

$fromdate = new DateTime($todate);
$diff = $fromdate->diff('now')->y;